# Visual basic UploadFile cannot connect to remote server

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I tried to upload file via Visual Basic with UploadFile function.

In documentation I found this step:

```
 My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(
      "C:\My Documents\Order.txt",
      "http://www.cohowinery.com/upload.aspx", "anonymous", "")
```

I tried it by myself, it works, but when the FTP ports (20,21) are disabled, it cannot works, and take an error, that is normal I know, but how to fix it? How to check the ports or, check the connection to FTP server before connection?

Generally I use:

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then...
```

but this works only with general of internet connection.

Any suggestions how to edit my code, to take down any error?

Comment: What do you want to fix? What do you want to do, if the upload fails/is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Try/Catch should work.

```
Try
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("","","","")
Catch ex As Exception
    'Error happened
End Try
```